# Plotting interaction effects of a cox-regression in R

Tags: r, graph, interaction, cox-regression

I am new to statistics and using R for which reason I struggle plotting interaction effects of a cox-regression in R.

I tried to find a suitable package and found simPH which could probably be useful, however, due to my lack of understanding of the description/manual I did not manage to implement it properly.

The code below shows my cox-regression (cox_prp). In this example i try to check, whether the interaction of inflation (Inf_E) with another variable (Kammer), leads to an earlier breakdown of governments.
I guess the function "coxsimInteract" (from the package simPH) could work but I honestly do not understand the manual of what the single parameters do.

```
cox_prop <- coxph(Surv(Duration, termination) ~ Inf_E*Kammer, data = daten)
```

I also tried code I found on the internet but this does not seem to work properly and I actually copied it without knowing what the parameters mean:

```
Sim2 <- coxsimInteract(cox_prop, b1 = "Inf_E", b2 = "Kammer", qi = "Marginal Effect", X2 = seq(2, 115, by = 2), nsim = 1000)

simGG(Sim2, ribbons = TRUE, alpha = 0.5, xlab = "Kammer\n", ylab = "Marginal effect of Inf_E\n")
```

Which function can plot the interaction, and how do the parameters need to be set?